# Bash: how to read and select a line with specific numbers?

Tags: bash

I have a table which is in `.txt` file. I want to pick a specific line. The line has to be picked by two columns which have for that line specific numbers.

For instance, I pick a line with numbers `21.497` and `54.6753`.

Working with a bash script.

```
21.480       54.6753        1.0000        1.6268         
21.497       54.6753        1.0167        1.6174         
21.514       54.6753        1.1941        1.5735         
21.531       54.6753        1.0383        1.5674
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! This is the place to get help - but please make sure you read all the [ask] pages, especially on a [mcve] of what you've tried. People are happy to help if you've shown you have at least made an effort... That said, please show us a sample of your effort, and what the input looks like. The more clear you can make your specs the better help you'll get. Off the cuff, it sounds like a `grep` or maybe `awk` problem. Be sure to specify your delimiters, and whether there can be multiples.

Comment: perhaps `awk '/2.1/ && /5.4/' file` is what you're after?

Comment: There is no line with a `2.1` or `5.4` in you example. Do you mean for `'.'` to match zero or more occurrences of any character between `2` and the `1`?

Comment: line=$(awk '/21.581/ && /54.6845/' pointfilename.txt) ; echo -e $line | tr -d '\n' >> opoint.txt That is how I wrote in the program, but it still does not work; something it picks; but does not print it

Comment: the numbers 2.1 and 5.4 I had written just as an example now I made it more concrete.

Comment: cross-posted https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/511839/72456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your_var=$(grep -F '21.514' your_file | grep -F '54.6753')
echo "$your_var"
```

> prints 21.514 54.6753 1.1941 1.5735

-F on grep is to treat the argument as a fixed string and not as a regex. So in this case it will treat dot as literal dot.

Comment: `-F` actually tells `grep` to treat the argument as a fixed string, not as a regex (this means more than just treating a dot as a literal).

Answer (score 0):

We might need a little more to help you out, like what does the input data look like, and what are you really trying to accomplish.

/tmp/foo:

```
2.1 3.8
1.1 5.4
2.1 5.4

$ grep '2.1 5.4' /tmp/foo
2.1 5.4
```

Comment: I copied a part of  data

Comment: I need to pick a line with numbers 21.514 and 54.6753. But not just numbers all line and make it as a variable.